# phonegap 3.3 iOS BarcodeScanner module not found

Tags: iphone, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am developing ios native application using Phonegap. This application has barcode scanning feature. It was working fine with phonegap version 2.9.0. Now, it is not working after I upgrade phonegap version 3.3.0.

It says "module cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner not found" if I use the following code

```
var scanner = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner');
scanner.scan(function1, function2);
```

It says undefined If I use the following code

```
window.plugins.barCodeScanner.scan(func1, func2);
```

It says undefined If I use the following code

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(func1, func2);
```

I used [this link](https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner/tree/9270025f71891b2f46a38b7bc3d1223b4955dce2) for this implementation. Please let me what am I doing wrong?

I have included barcodescanner.js and it is loaded when the app is loaded. I am sure about.
Also I am not getting any errors while building.

--Sridhar

Comment: Are you using the CLI to build your project? which platform are you testing?

Comment: Yes, I am using CLI for creating project, adding plugin and build my project. iOS platform and developing for iPhone5s.

Comment: in phonegap 3 you should not include phonegap.js, cordova.js nor any plugin javascript file (except if the plugin is not compatible with plugman). maybe you have issues because you manually added the plugin and plugman also includes it? you could also try to un-install and re-install the plugin using the cli.

Comment: I have installed inappbrowser plugin and facebook plugin using CLI without using plugman same as barcodescanner. Both plugins are working fine. How barcodescanner alone is not working. I tried re-installing the same plugins more than 2 times before I post this question.

Comment: actually, when you use the cli to install a plugin, you (indirectly) use plugman. Which repo did you use to install the barcode plugin (I've seen that there are several forks)

Comment: I have shared the link (barcodescanner repo) in my post.

Comment: seems that you are using the most up to date repository. Anyway you could have a look at this other post (seems outdated but who knows...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142247/phonegap-3-0-0-barcodescanner-plugin

Comment: thanks for responses, you asking me to downgrade the phonegap version to 3.0

Comment: no but you may test the repositories in the other post wich may have a fix for a similar problem

Comment: thanks. I have fixed. the file barcodescanner.js was some run-time issue. I have changed the line of code. It is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fixed. There is was run-time issue in barcodescanner.js. I found and fixed. It is working fine. The changed code.

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner", function (require, exports, module) {    
var exec = require("cordova/exec");
function BarcodeScanner() {
    this.Encode = {
    TEXT_TYPE: "TEXT_TYPE",
    EMAIL_TYPE: "EMAIL_TYPE",
    PHONE_TYPE: "PHONE_TYPE",
    SMS_TYPE: "SMS_TYPE"
        //  CONTACT_TYPE: "CONTACT_TYPE",  // TODO:  not implemented, requires passing a Bundle class from Javascript to Java
        //  LOCATION_TYPE: "LOCATION_TYPE" // TODO:  not implemented, requires passing a Bundle class from Javascript to Java
    };
};
BarcodeScanner.prototype.scan = function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
    if (errorCallback == null) {
        errorCallback = function () {
        };
    }
    if (typeof errorCallback != "function") {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.scan failure: failure parameter not a function");
        return;
    }
    if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.scan failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
        return;
    }
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'BarcodeScanner', 'scan', []);
};
BarcodeScanner.prototype.encode = function (type, data, successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
    if (errorCallback == null) {
        errorCallback = function () {
        };
    }
    if (typeof errorCallback != "function") {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.encode failure: failure parameter not a function");
        return;
    }
    if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
        console.log("BarcodeScanner.encode failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
        return;
    }
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'BarcodeScanner', 'encode', [
        {"type": type, "data": data, "options": options}
    ]);
};
var = new BarcodeScanner();
module.exports = barcodeScanner;
});
```