# Phonegap 3.3.0 cannot add any plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I am trying to add barcodescanner plugin to an Phonegap 3.3.0 project.

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ cordova create app de.app.name "app-name"
$ cd app
$ cordova platform add ios
$ cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner

Fetching plugin from "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner"...
Starting installation of "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" for ios
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Uh oh!
cannot find "/path/app/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm" ios <source-file>
    at module.exports.source-file.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/ios.js:44:48)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/action-stack.js:46:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:380:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:331:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

If I use the github link I get the same error in short:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner
Fetching plugin from "https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner"...
Starting installation of "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" for ios
Preparing ios project

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Also I get the same for the original version of the plugin:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner
```

I found a thread about a [problem in phonegap 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142247/phonegap-3-0-0-barcodescanner-plugin) but `https://github.com/jonathannaguin/BarcodeScanner` still gives me the same error.

I guess the importen part is `cannot find "/path/app/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm" ios`. Any thoughts how I can dig deeper into this and make it work?

**Update**

I got the same problem with `org.apache.cordova.console`. Also if I use `phonegap local plugin add ...`.

I notice that `www/config.xml` and `platforms/ios/www/config.xml` are broken. There is some binary empty space at the end of the file that can be removed. There might be something [messed up with phonegap itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279153/phonegap-3-3-0-config-xml-parsing-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by the directory I am in. If I do `cd ~` and run the same command it just works!

I was in `\Volumes/www` with is a **samba share** mounted over smbfs.