# Phonegap 3.3.0 config.xml parsing error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

It looks to me that Phonegap 3.3.0 broken. I do:

```
$ cordova create app de.app.name "app-name"
$ cd app
$ cordova platform add ios
```

Open the xcode project in `platforms/ios/*.xcodeproj` and run it (xcode 5.0.2). I get an Exception with a parsing error for config.xml.

I notice that `www/config.xml` and `platforms/ios/www/config.xml` are broken. There is some binary empty space at the end of the file. Removing that fixes the error but still I [cannot install any plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264579/phonegap-3-3-0-cannot-add-barcodescanner-plugin/21278198).

Does anyone else have this problem? How can I fix this?

**Update**
If I stick with phonegap commands things looking better:

```
$ phonegap create app de.app.name "app-name"
$ cd app
$ phonegap local build ios
```

`config.xml` looks fine now and does contain much more. `platforms/ios/www/config.xml` is bigger but still has the broken ending. Also plugin installation still does not work.

**Update 2**
Found a nice [tutorial](http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/using-phonegap-3-3-cli-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-to-build-ios-projects/) with does demand to use `cordova` instead of `phonegap` and does something like this:

```
cordova create App com.App.Name App
cd App
cordova platform add ios
cordova build ios
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
```

But still `platforms/ios/www/config.xml` is broken before I add the plugin and even with fixed config.xml it still throws the error. Same same. Also I tried reinstalling phonegap & cordova and restarting the Mac.

Comment: do try with com.app.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by the directory I am in. If I did `cd ~` and run the same command it just works!

I was in `\Volumes/www` with is a **samba share** mounted over smbfs.