# Working QR code scanner for PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have successfully followed this thread
[Phonegap 3.0.0: BarcodeScanner Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142247/phonegap-3-0-0-barcodescanner-plugin)

But it seems like it cannot scan Qr Code. Here is the screen shot from phone:

[image]

I have tried scanning a barcode image and it works fine. But not with QR images.
Any idea?

**EDIT**

```
    var scanner = cordova.require("com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.barcodescanner");

    scanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );
```

**EDIT 2**
DuuhhH!!! The problem was the QR image, it has no margin as Sean Owen said.

Comment: It's fine to me if you don't like the question and decide to close it. But can you please give some reason? I've been spending hours solving my problem.

Comment: That QR code does not have a margin, which is probably why it won't scan.

Comment: OMG, you're right. The QR code I used was generated from our api service. Basically it has no margin. Didn't know it was important. Thanks!!!!

Comment: what about other QR image?
I see QR Scanner app (in Apple store) can scan every QR image.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Copying from my comment as it seems to be the answer: That QR code does not have a margin, which is probably why it won't scan.